# How to plot a (22, 3, 2) matrix list of lists as a scatter plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot the below sensitivity matrix into a plot that consists of each list as sub-plot in it. Preferably as a function and look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVrVa.png) one in seaborn tutorial.

I tried a similar way to plot the list of list but it only give me a single plot without subplots:

```
def scatter_plot(sen1_obs):
    
    x = []

y = []
for i in sen1_obs:
    x.append(i[0])
    y.append(i[1])
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

And execute:

```
scatter_plot(sen1_obs)
```

My list look like this :

```
sen1_obs
Out[2]: 
[array([[ 0.00040725,  0.00011072],
        [ 0.0008145 ,  0.00022144],
        [-0.00040725, -0.00011072]]),
 array([[ 8.32091781e-04, -8.06469105e-05],
        [ 1.66418356e-03, -1.61293821e-04],
        [-8.32091781e-04,  8.06469105e-05]]),
 array([[ 0.00121915,  0.00033146],
        [ 0.00243829,  0.00066291],
        [-0.00121915, -0.00033146]]),
 array([[ 0.00252797, -0.00024503],
        [ 0.00505593, -0.00049006],
        [-0.00252797,  0.00024503]]),
 array([[ 0.00202743,  0.00055121],
        [ 0.00405486,  0.00110242],
        [-0.00202743, -0.00055121]]),
 array([[ 0.00430218, -0.00041706],
        [ 0.00860436, -0.00083411],
        [-0.00430218,  0.00041706]]),
 array([[ 3.08460052e-04,  8.38668514e-05],
        [ 6.16920103e-04,  1.67733703e-04],
        [-3.08460052e-04, -8.38668514e-05]]),
 array([[ 0.00132295, -0.00012862],
        [ 0.0026459 , -0.00025724],
        [-0.00132295,  0.00012862]]),
 array([[ 0.00089098,  0.00024225],
        [ 0.00178196,  0.0004845 ],
        [-0.00089098, -0.00024225]]),
 array([[ 0.00402754, -0.00039161],
        [ 0.00805507, -0.00078323],
        [-0.00402754,  0.00039161]]),
 array([[ 0.00149702,  0.00040703],
        [ 0.00299405,  0.00081405],
        [-0.00149702, -0.00040703]]),
 array([[ 0.00665672, -0.00064722],
        [ 0.01331343, -0.00129443],
        [-0.00665672,  0.00064722]]),
 array([[ 0.00879632,  0.00016573],
        [ 0.01759264,  0.00033147],
        [-0.00879632, -0.00016573]]),
 array([[ 0.00728856, -0.00055898],
        [ 0.01457712, -0.00111797],
        [-0.00728856,  0.00055898]]),
 array([[ 0.00913137, -0.00029702],
        [ 0.01826274, -0.00059403],
        [-0.00913137,  0.00029702]]),
 array([[ 0.00463152,  0.00026766],
        [ 0.00926303,  0.00053532],
        [-0.00463152, -0.00026766]]),
 array([[ 0.00315   ,  0.00014372],
        [ 0.0063    ,  0.00028743],
        [-0.00315   , -0.00014372]]),
 array([[ 0.00607034,  0.00023261],
        [ 0.01214067,
```

Comment: If the indentation of the function is your question is incorrect, could you edit your question so it is clearer what the function is doing. If the indentation is correct, the your function will never create a plot because the only thing your function does is create an empty list called x. You would need to indent the following lines as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this. I don't have a great way to use your data so disregard my first few lines of code that are making the data I am working with. But, essentially what you are doing is making a 5x5 grid to house your 22 subplots. You then create a list of lists for their positions in the subplot (we'll call it `pos`). You then iterate over all the arrays in your variable `en1_obs` and all the lists within your arrays. Delete the left over subplots (25-22 so 3 unused subplots) and you have your figure:

```py
######### This is just code to make a (22,3,2) matrix to work with #########
import random
en1_obs = []
for x in range(22):
    longlists = []
    for y in range(3):
        lists = []
        for z in range(2):
            lists.append(random.randint(1, 60))
        longlists.append(lists)
    en1_obs.append(np.array(longlists))
############################################################################

### This is the important code

plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = (20,10)    
width = 5
height = 5
fig, ax = plt.subplots(height,width)
pos = [[x,y] for x in range(height) for y in range(width)]

count = 0
for i in en1_obs:
    ax[pos[count][0],pos[count][1]].scatter(i[:, 0], i[:, 1])
    count +=1
fig.delaxes(ax[4,2])
fig.delaxes(ax[4,3])
fig.delaxes(ax[4,4])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for my unclearly worded question and I really appreciate your effort. The data is actually not 2 dimensional and the only reason it is in 3 x 2 is because there is 3 variables and 2 parameters to manipulate with for sensitivity analysis, and therefore I would like to show 6 data points in 22 sub-plots. I believe scattereplot api is not good for that. Any suggestion on the api I should use?

Answer (score 0):

The first point is to transform the data, so I am transforming it by changing the dimensions. The graph is drawn in a loop procedure with that transformed array. Empty graphs are manually deleted, so please adjust them. The number of data presented does not match the number of graphs, but please adjust the number of graphs to match my code to your data.

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(5, 4, figsize=(9,9))
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.5,hspace=0.5)

def scatter_plot(data):
    for d,ax in zip(data, axs.ravel()):
        xy = d.flatten().reshape(2,3, order='F')
        ax.scatter(xy[0], xy[1])
    fig.delaxes(axs[4,1])
    fig.delaxes(axs[4,2])
    fig.delaxes(axs[4,3])
    plt.show()

scatter_plot(data)
```

[image]

Comment: ravel is better than flatten in almost all cases

Comment: @Mad Thanks for the advice. I looked it up again and now I know why. Am I correct in understanding that the reason is superior in view and copy, speed and memory efficiency?

Comment: Correct. You got it!

Comment: Thank you for the effort! I also learned a lot from the discussion above too. I would like to know if I be able to use ravel to produce a 1 dimensional array to reshape it into 1 x 6 rather than a 2 dimensional graph? As the data is actually not for relation between x and y and the only reason it is in 3 x 2 is because there is 3 variables and 2 parameters to manipulate with for sensitivity analysis, and therefore I would like to show 6 data points in 22 sub-plots in this case.

Comment: To transform an array, use reshape, which can be done with reshape(6,1). With the three variables and two parameters you presented, what would be the values on the x- and y-axes? Also, other answers are accepted, is this because of data processing or graphing? Please let me know your reasons.